# Data migration using Java

Tags: java, mysql, json

I have a task like migrating from Oracle 10g to MySQL 5.5 using Java JDBC. Need help on how to accomplish the task.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First step is to [learn how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.5 is very old.  The latest is MySQL 8.  Why such an old version??